# Complexity Values for Specific Code/Functions

Tags: time-complexity, asymptotics, loops, big-o-notation

(1) Assume a function $f:\mathbb{Z^+}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ that's defined in a way that utilizes, say, *eight* basic computations, including addition, subtraction, division, multiplication, (positive square) root, and the floor function. We write a (Sage) program that involves a "for-loop" execution for $f(x)$ values ranging from 1 to $n$ with $n$ arbitrarily large. Is the time complexity of the program linear? I'm assuming the basic operations run in, essentially, $\mathcal{O}(1)$ time (even for large numbers). So, eight (constant-time) operations for each element within the for-loop is $8n$, which is $\mathcal{O}(n)$.

(2) Same as above, except we add a pair of "if" conditions to each execution within the loop. So, for each element (1 to $n$), we compute $f(x)$ and request 'if (f(x)).is_integer()==1', then 'if (f(x))%2==0', print(x); break'. If either conditional fails, simply continue the for-loop sequence. Wouldn't this also be $\mathcal{O}(n)$ complexity? Worst case, we have ten (constant-time) operations for the entire loop (i.e., eight mathematical operations and two conditionals per loop element): $10n\rightarrow\mathcal{O}(n)$?

Comment: How long does it take `is_integer()` in your model of computation? Depending on your choice this step could take infinite time, or not.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I'm just using the standard function in Sage Math 9.0. My guess is Sage subtracts the value from the floor-function of the value and checks to see if that value equals zero.

Comment: You need to understand that you are not using Sage or anything real in your question. You are modeling. For example, when you say that you are assuming that the basic operations run in $O(1)$ time with respect to $n$, you are modeling. In reality this is not true. My question is how is `is_integer()` done in your model? To answer this you might need to answer, how are the outputs of $f$, which you said are real numbers modeled? Examples of possible choices: They could be infinite streams of the decimal digits of the output of $f$. They could be expressions, like $\sqrt{2}+\sin(\pi^e)$.

Comment: They could be approximate values, like the closest representable double precision floating point number. There are many choices. In the first example, `is_integer()` would take infinite time. In the second example, if the expressions are complicated it could be undecidable, but with some restrictions there are algorithms to implement `is_integer()`. In the last example, well, I guess `is_integer()` can say if the approximation is an integer and work in $O(1)$.

Comment: I can't provide an answer. Apparently, Sage chooses the universe with the most precision, and I assume outputs are rational expressions (or their decimal representations). In any case, the first program doesn't use the "is_integer()" function, so can I assume the complexity is $\mathcal{O}(n)$ in that case? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Anyone else with thoughts?

Comment: @u220e Yes in the first scenario we expect a runtime of $O(n)$ given that all the operations mentioned take $O(1)$.
With regards to your second question I want to add that if you simply declare "is equal to zero" as a constant operation like you did with the other operations your problem is solved.

Comment: Thank you. Much appreciated.